# regular expression how do I make it stop looking

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex which matches the first 3 lines below (the rest are tests cases which I do NOT want to catch)

```
Sample text for testing:
10:00:00+10:00/mon,thu
10:00:00+10:00/mon-thu
10:00:00+10:00/mon

10:00:00+10:00/monday-thu
10:00:00+10:00/mon-thursday
10:00:00+10:00/mon,,,thu
10:00:00+10:00/mon,
10:00:00+10:00/mon+thu
10:00:00+10:00/monthu
10:00:00+10:00/
21:00:00+10:00\sat-sun
```

So far I have come up with

```
[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[+][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}([/][a-z]{3}){1}([,-][a-z]{3})?
```

but as you can see it makes the matches I want but it also includes cases where there are trailing characters which I do not want and when there are trailing characters it should not be a match.

[image]

Comment: Is what you are looking for always going to have that extra empty line? Why not just look for an extra `\n` at the end of your regex? Would that work? Or look for empty line?

Comment: @idjaw His regexp only matches one line at a time.

Comment: Hi idjaw thanks for the reply. I would like to be more specific. These values will be entered by humans, so they could literally put anything. I was hoping to try and limit what they put into exactly only match the first 3 cases of my sample text

Comment: Just find the differences between the match lines and the others and the simliarities between the match lines. Your expression looks way too complicated.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I was playing around with it in regex101 and came up with a naive assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$` to the end of the regexp. This matches the end of the line, so it will prevent matches if there's anything after it.

You should also put `^` at the beginning so it doesn't match if there's anything before the time.

Comment: Hi Barmar I added the $ to the end of the line and this resulted in no matches being made in my sample text. I used http://regexr.com/ to do this

Comment: Use the `m` option so that `$` matches the end of line instead of end of string.

Comment: Hey Barmar, I tried to find some documentation on what this option actually does https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M without much luck. I need to understand what this is doing so I know that this is the correct approach for this regex.

Comment: You may only need it at `regexr.com`, since you're processing multiple lines at once in the test case. If your application is only processing one line at a time, it doesn't need it.

Comment: `m` makes `^` and `$` match newlines between lines, in addition to the beginning and end of the input string.

Comment: Thanks for the help Barmar. using http://regexr.com/ wasn't the best idea for me as you are correct, the value should only be one line at a time. By adding the $ at the end of my regex it is now passing unit tests